# ggplot2: Remove first word of axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

When I run this script I get the following plot:

```
ggplot(fgseaResTidy %>% filter(padj < 0.05) %>% head(n= 20), aes(reorder(pathway, NES), NES)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill= NES > 5)) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="Pathway", y="Normalized Enrichment Score",
       title="Hallmark pathways NES from GSEA") + 
      theme(axis.text.y.left = element_text(size = 10)) +
      scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) stringr::str_trunc(x, 40, "right"))
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

I have tried truncating the `scale_x_discrete` labels to shorten the labels, but I want to remove the "REACTOME_" part which is at the front of each label. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your time!
Naomi

Answer (score 2):

This is not (neccesarily) an issue with ggplot but simple data-manipulation prior to calling ggplot.

1st, try moving your data.frame manipulation outside of ggplot:

```
fgseaResTidy %>% filter(padj < 0.05) %>% head(n= 20) %>%
ggplot(aes(reorder(pathway, NES), NES)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill= NES > 5)) +
  ...
```

(it simply improves readability)

Next, do a search and replace on `REACTOME_`:

```
fgseaResTidy %>% filter(padj < 0.05) %>% head(n= 20) %>%
mutate(pathway = sub("REACTOME_", "", pathway, fixed=TRUE)) %>%
ggplot(aes(reorder(pathway, NES), NES)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill= NES > 5)) +
  ...
```

Depending on whether `REACTOME_` appears other places in the pathway name, you might want to use regular expressions in `sub`, i.e. `sub("^REACTOME\\_", "", pathway)`.

**Edit:**

Well, strictly speaking you could also just remove the text in your call to `scale_x_discrete`:

```
scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) {
  x %>% sub("REACTOME_", "", .) %>% stringr::str_trunc(40, "right"))
})
```

Comment: Brilliant, I used scale_x_discrete(label = function(x) {
  x %>% sub("REACTOME_", "", .) %>% stringr::str_trunc(40, "right"))
})

and that worked perfectly. Thank you for your time :)